# How to disallow certain page to be viewed i.e. success.xhtml

Tags: jsf-2

I would like to check how to manage contexts / pages that are displayable to users.

For example, to allow /register.xthml, but not /success.xhtml.

Thx.

Comment: Disallow to who? Not-logged-in users?

Comment: For example, /success.xhtml is displayed to the user as a result of a success registration through /register.xhtml. But the user shouldn't be able to access /success.xhtml directly. In the sense yes, disallowed to not-logged-in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one possible way, by hiding them in the web information folder WEB-INF.